# HI, I trying to make a REST API call to external Application from Cloud page, But getting 500 internal error

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, cloudpage

I trying to make a REST API POST request to an external Application from the Cloud page But getting 500 internal error. Can you please help me out with this on what mistake I'm doing

```
%%[
    set @uname = "Harish"
    set @pwd = "Password"
    set @auth = Concat(@uname, @pwd)
    set @url = "https://endpointurl.com"
    
    set @payload = '{
        "addSeminarCustomerInputField":{
            "seminarCustomerField":{
                "additionalAttendeesField":0,
                "confirmedField":true,
                "customer_IDField":1170, 
                "isHandicappedField":false,
                "isHearingImpairedField":false,
                "isVisionImpairedField":false,
                "notesField":"Test Notes",
                "seminar_IDField":3
            }
        }
    }'
     
      SET @req = HTTPPost2(@url, "application/json", @payload, false, @response, "Authorization", @auth)
      
      
     ]%%
    
    Res = %%=v(@response)=%%
```

[image]

**Postman code:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://endpointurl.com' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Q0JDX0FQSTpjYmNhcGkyMDIw' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=on4xa3ow4hta45lipltm5x0w' \
--data-raw '{
    "addSeminarCustomerInputField":{
        "seminarCustomerField":{
            "additionalAttendeesField":0,
            "confirmedField":true,
            "customer_IDField":1170,
            "isHandicappedField":false,
            "isHearingImpairedField":false,
            "isVisionImpairedField":false,
            "notesField":"Test Notes",
            "seminar_IDField":3
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Have you verified if the call is correct? If the post does not return 200 status, then the whole page will toss an exception

Comment: @Gortonington: Yes. I test in Postman and it worked and returned 200 status.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is because in your HTTPPost2 function itself.
Based on the [documentation](https://ampscript.guide/httppost2/) the parameters are as followed:

[image: parameters]

Please pay attention to parameter 5 and 6 in your code:

```
SET @req = HTTPPost2(@url, "application/json",  @payload, false, "Authorization", @auth,  @response)
```

You have moved your `@response` variable to #7
The correct way would be:

```
SET @req = HTTPPost2(@url, "application/json",  @payload, false, @response, "Authorization", @auth)
```

---

**Edit:**

My code example was missing parameter 6 as I have described above:

```
SET @req = HTTPPost2(@url, "application/json",  @payload, false, @response, @responseRowSet, "Authorization", @auth)
```

`ResponseRowSet` need to be set as parameter 6 not your first header value.

Also, you should review Authentication vs Authorization. If you stick with Authorization please have a read at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

You may want to change your `@auth` variable to:

```
set @auth = Concat('Basic ',Base64Encode(Concat(@uname,':',@pwd)))
```

Comment: I tried according to your comments, but no luck. Still the same error.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: I have updated it according to your comments. I got an Access Denied response (I have attached the response screenshot above). If it's because of user ID & Password, but it worked in postman with the same credentials.

Comment: As your code is rendering fine, the issue is not with the code itself but a logical issue with your endpoint. This is out of scope for salesforce.stackexchange. What I would suggest is that you take your working Postman call and click on "Code"  on the top right hand side. You will be able to see the actual call and what you may need to change in your header to achieve the same result

Comment: I have updated the post with the working Postman code. What changes do you think I should make?

Comment: Please try to use: set @auth = Concat('Basic ',Base64Encode(Concat(@uname,':',@pwd)))